# Prove/Disprove: There exists a normal operator $\phi :\mathbb{C}^4 \to\mathbb{C}^4$ in standard unitary space $\mathbb{C}^4$ s.t. the following holds

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Prove/Disprove:** There exists a normal operator $ \phi : \mathbb{C}^4 \to \mathbb{C}^4 $ in standard unitary space $ \mathbb{C}^4 $ s.t.
$\varphi\left(\begin{array}{l}1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \\ 0\end{array}\right)= 
\left(\begin{array}{l}2 \\ 0 \\ 4 \\ 0\end{array}\right), \quad \varphi\left(\begin{array}{c}-2 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}-6 \\ 3 \\ 3 \\ 3\end{array}\right)$

**Attempt:** I was going to find out the indication for the answer by letting $ A = \left[\begin{array}{cccc} x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 \\ x_5 & x_6 & x_7 & x_8 \\ x_9 & x_{10} & x_{11} & x_{12} \\ x_{13} & x_{14} & x_{15} & x_{16}  \end{array}\right]$ denote the alleged matrix representation for the normal operator if it exists. Then,  $ A \left(\begin{array}{l}1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \\ 0\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{l} x_1+2x_3 \\ x_5+2x_7 \\ x_9+2x_{11} \\ x_{13}+2x_{15} \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{l}2 \\ 0 \\ 4 \\ 0\end{array}\right)  $ ,
$ A \left(\begin{array}{c}-2 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{array}\right) =
\left(\begin{array}{l} -2x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 \\ -2x_5+x_6+x_7+x_8 \\ -2x_9+x_{10}+x_{11}+x_{12} \\ -2x_{13}+x_{14}+x_{15}+x_{16} \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{l} -6 \\ 3 \\ 3 \\ 3 \end{array}\right) $, Then I'd create few more equations for the condition $ A A^* = A^* A $ ( because I want $ A $ to be normal ), I'd solve for $ x_1,...,x_{16} $ and that's it.

The main problem with this method is that it is extremely long, error prone. I was wondering how would you solve this problem? I feel there's a better way that takes advantage of that fact that we're dealing with standard unitary space but I just can't see it.

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $u_1 = (0,1,0,2)^T$ and $u_2 = (-2,1,1,1)^T$. We are given that these vectors are eigenvectors, with $\varphi(u_1) = 2u_1$ and $\varphi(u_2) = 3u_2$. Notably, the vectors $u_1,u_2$ are mutually orthogonal.

With the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Finite-dimensional_case) in mind, how can this operator be extended to a normal operator over $\Bbb C^4$?

---

The simplest example of such an operator $\varphi$ is the map for which $\varphi|_{\{u_1,u_2\}^\perp} = 0$. The matrix of this map relative to the standard basis can be expressed directly as
$$
\varphi = 2\frac{u_1u_1^*}{u_1^*u_1} + 3\frac{u_2u_2^*}{u_2^*u_2}.
$$

Comment: After reading more about the spectral theorem in the link, I took the orthogonal spaces: $ K_1 = span\{ u_1 \}^\perp = span\{ (0,-2,0,1),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1) \} $ ,  $ K_2 = span\{ u_2 \}^\perp = span\{ (1,2,0,0),(0,-1,1,0),(0,-1,0,1) \} $, and it can be said that
$ \mathbb{C}^4 = span\{u_1 \}^\perp  \oplus span\{u_1 \} = span\{u_2 \}^\perp  \oplus span\{u_2 \}  $.

Comment: I'm not sure how to continue now though, I thought I'd find vectors $ \tau_1,\tau_2 $ where $ \tau_1 \in K_1 , \tau_2 \in K_2$ s.t. $ \{ u_1,u_2 , \tau_1,\tau_2 \} $ is an orthogonal basis but then I'd be pretty much stuck on that point since I don't know how $ \phi $ will operate on these other basis vectors.

Comment: @hazelnut_116 You're on the right track. That said, you don't need to actually find such vectors, merely note that they can be found. Because those vectors are linearly independent to $u_1,u_2,$ anything that $\phi$ does to the vectors $\tau_1,\tau_2$ corresponds to a linear map of some kind. I think that the simplest way to extend $\phi$ is to take both $\tau_1,\tau_2$ to be eigenvectors of $\phi$ associated with eigenvalue $0$. As long as we take $\tau_1,\tau_2$ to be eigenvectors, the resulting map $\phi$ will be normal.

Comment: @hazelnut_116 Another approach to consider: an operator is normal iff its matrix $A$ with respect to *any orthonormal basis* is normal (in the sense of commuting with its conjugate transpose). So, consider the matrix of $\varphi$ with respect to the basis $\{u_1,u_2,\tau_1,\tau_2\}$, noting again that there is no need to find $\tau_1,\tau_2$ explicitly.  The given information tells us that the matrix of $\varphi$ relative to this basis has the form
$$
A  = \pmatrix{2 & 0 &?&?\\0&3&?&?\\0&0&?&?\\0&0&?&?}.
$$
Note that diagonal matrices are normal.